# Como consultar a DB sem refresh e escrever os dados retornados?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

Preciso consultar o meu banco de dados com alguma coisa do tipo AJAX/JSON não tenho certeza e retornar o resultado dentro de uma `div` ao lado deste **[mapa](http://stanley.axitech.com.br/pontos-de-atendimento)**. Já existe uma `div` ao lado para receber o resultado da consulta.

Não tenho certeza de como posso começar a fazer isto mas criei o script PHP que fará a consulta, segue:

```
<?php

require("conexao.php");

$estado     = $_GET['b_estado'];
$ret        = mysql_query("SELECT post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'estados' AND post_title = '$estado' AND post_status = 'publish'");

$array     = mysql_fetch_assoc($ret);
$dados     = $array['post_content'];

json_encode($dados);

?>
```

Como fazer para que essa ação seja disparada com o seguinte *script* em jQuery?

```
$("#map li a").on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

    var estado = $(this).attr("id");
    var b_estado = estado.toUpperCase();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Coloque este código dentro de alguma function que irá ser chamada pra fazer o que vc quer, lembre-se para extrair do response os dados que vc quer.

Eu não testei o código mas é basicamente isso que vc tem que fazer, qualquer coisa vc faz uns ajustes, se quiser eu posso dar uma melhorada na resposta depois:

```
var url = "seuArquivo.php";
var data = b_estado;
$.ajax({                 
        type: 'POST',                 
        //dataType: 'json',                 
        url: url,                 
        async: true,                 
        data: data,                 
        success: function(response) {
            $("#idSuaDiv").val(response);
            //vc pode fazer outras coisas aqui com a resposta
        }             
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Este código que segue permite que a consulta acima citada seja feita no banco de dados e retorne os dados requisitados através de `AJAX`.

```
$("#map li a").on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

    // Recupero os dados para enviar para a consulta
    var estado = $(this).attr("id");
    var b_estado = estado.toUpperCase();

        // Faço uma requisição AJAX para tratar o script PHP
        $.ajax  ({  type: "POST", 
            url         : "consulta_estados.php",
            data        : { b_estado: b_estado },
            dataType    : "html",
            success     : function(result){ 
                $("#infos_atendimento").html(result);   
            }

    }); // AJAX

}); // CLICK
```

O script PHP que executa e retorna os dados é este:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8", true);
require("conexao.php");

$estado     = $_POST['b_estado'];

if( isset($_POST['b_estado']) ){

    $ret            = mysql_query("SELECT post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'estados' AND post_title = '$estado' AND post_status = 'publish'");
    $contador       = mysql_num_rows($ret);
    $array      = mysql_fetch_assoc($ret);
    $dados      = $array['post_content'];       

if($contador > 0){  
    $resposta   = utf8_encode($array['post_content']);  
} else {    
    $resposta   = "Os dados solicitados não existem";   
}

echo $resposta;

}

?>
```