# Como dar refresh em outra pagina após inserir dados no banco

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, json

eu estou criando um sistema de atendimento onde existe uma tela só para exibir as senhas que estão sendo cadastradas no banco de dados.

O problema é que eu não consigo atualizar as senhas em tempo real, pq estou chamando elas de outra pagina, eu só consegui utilizando esquemas de ficar atualizando a pagina a cada certo tempo, eu gostaria de saber se consigo fazer isso assíncrona junto com ajax.

Esse é código da tela que chama as senhas

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function Att() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '../SenhaController',
                data: 'json',
                success: function (data) {          
                    $.each(data.nomeNormal, function (idx, obj) {
                        $('#tabelaNorm').ready().append("<tr><td>" + obj.nomeNormal + "</td><tr>");
                    });
                    $.each(data.nomePref, function (idx, obj) {
                        $('#tabelaPref').ready().append("<tr><td>" + obj.nomePref + "</td><tr>");
                    });
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

E esse é onde eu cadastro as senhas

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#submit').click(function (event) {

                    var username = $('#name').val();
                    var senha = $("input[name='senha']:checked").val();

                    $.getJSON('../gerarSenha', {user: username, senha: senha}, function (resposta) {

                        $('#resultado').html(resposta.respostaNormal).fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut();
                        $('#resultado').html(resposta.respostaPref).fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut();
                        $('#name').val('');
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Certeza que quer usar refresh?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38467/como-consultar-a-db-sem-refresh-e-escrever-os-dados-retornados?rq=1 - Duplicata?

Comment: Não necessariamente, eu só preciso que os dados da tela de senha sejam atualizados assim que eu inserir uma nova senha no banco, o problema é que a tela de senha está em outra página e eu não consigo fazer isso, já rodei o fórum com diversos problemas parecidos porem nenhum igual

Comment: Tudo bem, desculpe o engano, acredito que seria ótimo a utilização disso vai ajudar muita gente, favoritei a pergunta pra ver a resposta mais tarde ;)

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, uma pagina vc cadastra a senha no banco de dados, a outra página vc busca as senhas. Porém queria que isso fosse em tempo "real"?

Comment: Isso mesmo lionbtt, eu tenho uma pagina que faço o cadastro dessas senhas tipo uma "Triagem", a pagina que exibe as senhas elas só buscam via ajax, ai eu queria que essa pagina atualizasse em tempo real, se precisar atualizar a pagina para aparecer o proximo

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro, alguns frameworks como o MeteorJS lidam muito bem com este tipo de cenario, em todo caso você vai precisar fazer uma alteração no lado do Servidor para alcançar o resultado esperado. Então, o que voce está usando no lado do servidor?

Comment: Vou dar uma pesquisada sobre esse MeteorJS, estou trabalhando com java tratamento pela Servlet

Answer (score -1):

Como no modelo *cliente x servidor* você não mantém uma conexão persistente com o servidor, no caso quando uma requisição é enviada para ser processada, ao ser respondida essa conexão acaba e você não têm mais a refêrencia da página que fez essa requisição, o que impossibilitaria fazer o que você está tentando, porém, existem algumas formas de se fazer isso:

1. Atualizar a página que você quer a informação de tempos em tempos, também pode ser utilizado ajax para fazer um GET sem atualizar a página toda.
2. Utilizar WebSockets que simulam uma "conexão persistente" com o servidor, dessa forma, quando você abrisse a página que deseja essa informação em tempo real, ela simularia uma conexão persistente ao seu servidor e a manteria sem perdê-la (desde que você persista isso em algum lugar, num mapa estático por exemplo), assim quando houvesse um insert você dispararia um evento que notificaria essa página em questão, podendo fazer um broadcast para todas as conexões ou notificação apenas para uma página específica.
3. De acordo com a documentação do [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), se você executar window.open e especificar o nome dessa página, a próxima vez que você executar essa função a página será sobrescrita com a url que você forncerá, portanto, se você passar a mesma deve funcionar um refresh, porém esse método só funcionaria se você tivesse abrido a segunda página a partir da primeira.

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se ajuda, afinal essa pergunta foi a 6 anos atrás kskss.
Mas você pode fazer requisição com o servidor, sempre que o banco confirmar a entrada de dados, a sua página pode enviar um boolean (true) para o servidor, ai enquanto o servidor tiver false, ele não faz nada, mas assim que receber um true da página ele envia um true para a sua página de consulta, que vai dar um refresh automático depois de receber a resposta.